# Etiqueta html inaccesible bs4 en python

Tags: python

Es posible que no pueda acceder a la etiqueta que define el color de este articulo?. Probe de varias forma para poder acceder pero se me hace imposible.
Les comparto el código a ver si alguien me puede orientar un poco.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

 url = "https://47street.com.ar/canguro-snake-oversize-color-unico.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
```

A la etiqueta que estoy intentando ingresar es a:

*" < div class="swatch-option image" option-type="2" option-id="255"> **option-label="ColorUnico"**
 option-tooltip-thumb ="https://47street.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/swatch_image/55x69/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/c/a/cangurosnakeoesize12251.jpg"
 option-tooltip-value="https://47street.com.ar/media/catalog/product/cache/s
 no-repeat center; background-size: initial ;">< / div>"*

**Y solo es visible inspeccionando el elemento desde la web.**

Intentos de llegar a la etiqueta:

```
[i for i in soup.find_all(class_="swatch-option image")]
>>[]

[i for i in soup.find_all(class_="swatch-attribute-options clearfix")] 
>>[]
```

pd: Tuve que poner unos espacios en la etiqueta porque sino no me dejaba copiarla.

Comment: ¿Has analizado  el html que obtienes en `requests.get(url).text`?, segun veo alli no existe, el elemento que señalas esta creado con js despues de la carga.

Comment: Por eso preguntaba si se podía acceder, gracias.

Comment: Seguramente necesites atacar el problema de otra forma. Te recomiendo que investigues por el lado de [`selenium`[(https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html), la idea de este paquete es que básicamente interactuas con la página  tal como lo haría un usuario mediante un navegador, por lo que podrías acceder a los objetos dinámicos que normalmente se dibujan mediante javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Investigando un poco el modulo *Selenium*, gracias a uno de los comentarios sugerido. Pudé localizar la etiqueta, ya que a simple vista, la etiqueta se hace visible al activar el evento `Click()`. A continuación comparto el código que utilicé para poder resolver la consigna, no es el más eficiente. Aún sigo investigando, como por ejemplo "¿Por qué se abre la pagina al ejecutar el código?".(Eso me hace mucho ruido ya que si necesito hacerlo para un *web scraping* que obtiene productos en masa, sería prácticamente inservible.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://47street.com.ar/canguro-snake-oversize-color-unico.html")
generate = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='swatch-option image']")
generate.click()
time.sleep(2)
page = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"html5lib")
tag = page.find_all(class_="swatch-attribute-selected-option")

browser.close()

tag 
>>[<span class="swatch-attribute-selected-option">ColorUnico</span>, <span class="swatch-attribute-selected-option"></span>] 
tag = tag[0].get_text() 
tag
>>'ColorUnico'
```

Comment: Revisa la documentación, hay una configuración que no recuerdo bien, para que el navegador quede oculto.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo previsualizar el código de alguna manera para analizarlo, en este caso podrías hacer un

***print(soup.prettify())***

para mostrarlo por pantalla y ver si existe tal etiqueta, clase css o lo que sea que busques.

Lo acabo de ejecutar y tal como te comentan arriba y no localizo ninguna clase 'swatch-xxx', sin embargo si puedo obtener el contenido de otras, por ejemplo 'desktop':

[image: Ejemplo con prettify y clase 'desktop']

Un saludo!